# Rxjs (4,5) shorthand for filtering values

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is there a shortcut for filtering values:

Something like:

```
.filterValues(['POP', 'PUSH'])
```

Instead of this:

```
.filter(action => action == 'POP' || action === 'PUSH')
```

?

Searched through docs, maybe missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none that I know of. That said, you can always write your own utility function and/or use underscore/lodash and/or use ramda or other functional library. `_.eq` could for example be used if you have only one value in your filter values array. `Array.prototype.indexOf`, or `R.indexOf` can also be used in conjunction with `R.compose` and `R.gt`. But the dummiest and simplest way to go is :

```
var utils = {}
utils.filterValues = function (arr) { 
  return function (value) { return arr.indexOf(value) > -1}
}
```

and then `.filter(utils.filterValues(['POP', 'PUSH']))`